# cakephp2でフロント画面と管理画面を分ける際のURLについて

Tags: cakephp

cakephp2.x にて、フロント画面と管理画面を分けるサイトを作成したいです。
それぞれprefixを使って、

front
admin

とした場合、そのままだと

hogehoge.com/front
hogehoge.com/admin

となると思いますが、これを front の方だけはトップディレクトリ

hogehoge.com/

adminは
hogehoge.com/admin

としたいのですが、可能でしょうか？

frontはプレフィックスを使わないという方法は考えたのですが、プレフィックスを使ってルーティングなどで実現する方法はありますでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 可能です、が曖昧なのでコメントで回答します。
htaccessか、index.php側で調整した記憶があります。
思い出したら正式に回答します。

Comment: ありがとうございます。やはり可能なのですね。ぜひ思い出したら宜しくお願いします。